# What values should be set to registers when calling pthread_create in assembly code?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, pthreads, x86-64

For learning purposes, I am trying to create a toy assembly program that runs a function in a separate thread. My machine has the x86-64 architecture and runs the Ubuntu OS. I use the `pthread` library for this purpose:

```
extern pthread_create
extern pthread_join

section .data
    ; a separate thread will print the "Hello" message
    text: db "Hello", 10
    text_len: equ $-text
    thread_id: dq 0

section .text
global main
main:
    mov eax, 0
    mov ecx, 0
    mov edx, thread ; the function address to be executed in a thread
    
    ; With the "mov esi, 0" instruction, the call to pthread_create
    ; throws a segfault. Without this instruction, the call to
    ; pthread_create returns, but produces no observable effect.
    mov esi, 0

    mov rdi, thread_id
    call pthread_create

    mov eax, 0
    mov rsi, 0
    mov rdi, [thread_id]
    ; this call should block until the thread terminates, shouldn't it?
    call pthread_join
    ret

thread:
    ; printing "Hello" to the screen
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, text
    mov edx, text_len
    int 80h
    ret
```

I compile the executable `a.out` file with the following commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 code.s
gcc -no-pie code.o -lpthread
```

The executable fails to run properly, with the errors indicated in the code.
I suspect the failure reason is the wrong set up of the register arguments before calling the `pthread_create`.
**How to set up the arguments correctly?**

UPDATE:

I changed the `pthread_create` arguments to

```
mov eax, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov edx, thread_0
mov rdi, thread0_id
```

and the `pthread_join` arguments to

```
mov eax, 0
mov ecx, 0
mov rdi, thread0_id
```

Now the code throws a `bus error`. Could it be that the `pthread_t` does not have a permission to print the message?

Comment: Suggest you write a working example in C, and see what the compiler does, and replicate that.

Comment: You need to pass a pointer to a `pthread_t`, you're using the []'s which means value not address, I believe.

Comment: `thread_id: dw 0` should be `dq`. Also, do not use `int 80h` from 64 bit code. Anyway, the code works here.

Comment: I would be concerned that you don't have proper stack alignment (16-bytes)

Comment: I can reproduce a segfault on a SIMD aligned instruction on Ubuntu 20.04. As I mentioned in my last comment you need a 16 byte aligned stack at the point of a call. To align the stack on a 16 byte stack boundary push a register (like `push rbp`) at the beginning of the function `main` and then you can pop it of with `pop rbp` before doing the `ret`.

Comment: At the point just before `main` is called by the C startup code the stack is aligned on a 16 byte boundary (Per the [AMD64 System V ABI](https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf)). At the first instruction of the function `main` the stack is misaligned by 8 since the return address was pushed on the stack by the `call` instruction (or equivalent). Pushing 8 bytes on the stack realigns it back to 16 bytes which is needed by the calls the the pthread library code.

Comment: @MichaelPetch indeed it works now, thx.